# PHP | Object not found! Simple CRUD

Tags: php

I am still trying out PHP and with database capability. I'm new to stack overflow as well.
I'm having a problem with updating and deleting a row in my database but for now updating is the concern and surely deletion will follow if I manage to get assisted for this.
I have database "dbSample" and it has 3 columns "id, name, address, email".
I am having problems redirecting correctly to my update classes and it shows an error every time.
[image: Object Not Found img]

**Below is the said connection file:(sample/class/dbconnection.php):**

```
    <?php

    /*
    ==============================SQL Connection=================================
      */

    $connections = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbSample"); //checks database connection
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . "Database Status: " . mysqli_connect_error() . '")</script>';
        }

    ?>
```

**Below serves as my index php file(sample/dbsample.php):**

```
<?php require 'class/dbconnection.php';?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<?php include 'class/dbupdate.php'; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Below is the said dbupdate file:(sample/class/dbupdate.php):**

```
<?php

/*
==============================SQL Update=================================
  */

$view_query = mysqli_query($connections, "SELECT * FROM tblSample");

echo "<table border = '1'>";
echo "<tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Email</td>

        <td>Option</td>

        </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($view_query)){ //make variables to hold the values from the table

    $user_id = $row["id"];

    $db_name = $row["name"];
    $db_address = $row["address"];
    $db_email = $row["email"];

    //get the value id and pass it
    echo "<tr>
        <td>$db_name</td>
        <td>$db_address</td>
        <td>$db_email</td>

        <td><a href='class/updatepass.php?id=$user_id'>Update</a></td>

        </tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

**Below is the said updatepass file:(sample/class/updatepass.php):**

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__."\dbconnection.php");

$user_id = $_REQUEST["id"];

$get_record = mysqli_query($connections, "SELECT * FROM tblSample WHERE id='$user_id'");

while($row_edit = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_record)){
    $db_name = $row_edit["name"];
    $db_address = $row_edit["address"];
    $db_email = $row_edit["email"];
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="class/updatenow.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
    Name: <input type="text" name="new_name" value="<?php echo $db_name; ?>">

    <hr />

    Address: <input type="text" name="new_address" value="<?php echo $db_address; ?>">

    <hr />

    Email: <input type="text" name="new_email" value="<?php echo $db_email; ?>">

    <hr />

    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

**Below is the said updatenow file:(sample/class/updatenow.php):**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

require_once(__DIR__."\class\updatepass.php");
require_once(__DIR__."\class\dbconnection.php");

$user_id = $_POST["id"];

$new_name = $_POST["new_name"];
$new_address = $_POST["new_address"];
$new_email = $_POST["new_email"];

mysqli_query($connections, "UPDATE tblSample SET name='$new_name', address='$new_address', email='$new_email' WHERE id='$user_id'");

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . "Record has been updated" . '")</script>';
header('location: dbsample.php');

?>
```

*Thank you for the help in advance, I will deeply appreciate it.*

Comment: In your last `location: dbsample.php`, shouldn't that be `location: sample/dbsample.php`?

Comment: Just put your full url.... eg http://example.com/dbsample.php ....

Comment: That would be a bad thing to do

Comment: 404 Error occurred when resources or page you visit is not found. I expect there's something wrong with the url of resources/page, try checking the url

Comment: @NigelRen this part works apparently..

Comment: @arisalsaila Indeed, the error pops out whenever I try press the button to save edited values. it points out that object cannot found "updatepass.php" but it just came there. :(